# Unable to validate hypersonic flatplate case in DSMC SPARTA

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, aerodynamics

I'm trying to learn a software called [DSMC SPARTA](https://sparta.github.io/). I'm validating the hypersonic flatplate case mentioned in one of the [tutorials](https://sparta.github.io/pdf/sparta_validation_verification.pdf) on the website (Page 17). This was my test case:

```
seed                12345
dimension           2
global              gridcut 0.0 comm/sort yes
units               si

boundary            o r p

create_box          -0.06 0.12 -0.1025 0.1025 -0.05 0.05
create_grid         360 410 1 
balance_grid        rcb cell

global              nrho 371600000000000000000 vstream 1504.0 0 0 fnum 456000000000

species             air.species N O
mixture             air N O temp 13.32 

read_surf           data.lid
surf_collide        1 diffuse 290.0 0.0
surf_modify         all collide 1

collide             vss air air.vss

fix                 in emit/face air xlo twopass

timestep            3.102e-7

compute             1 grid all air n u v temp
compute             2 eflux/grid all air heatx heaty heatz
fix                 1 ave/grid all 1 100 100 c_2[*]
dump                1 grid all 100 dump.myforce.* id c_1[*]
dump                2 grid all 100 tmp.grid.* id f_1[*]

stats               100
stats_style         step cpu np nattempt ncoll nscoll nscheck
run                 10000
```

The number of particles shown in the log file are close to 31448306, but as compared to this [publication](https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/1372010) (Page 7), the number of particles are off by an order of 10. I'm unable to understand what the problem is.

Additional information:

air.species file

```
# Species data
# ID
# Molwt (amu)
# Molmass (kg)
# Rotational dof
# RotRel
# Vibrational dof
# VibRel
# VibTemp (K)
# species wt
# charge

O2  32.00    5.31E-26  2    0.2   2    5.58659E-5    2256.0    1.0      0.0
N2  28.016   4.65E-26  2    0.2   2    1.90114E-5    3371.0    1.0      0.0
O   16.00    2.65E-26  0    0.0   0    0.0           0.0       1.0      0.0
N   14.008  2.325E-26  0    0.0   0    0.0           0.0       1.0      0.0
NO  30.008   4.98E-26  2    0.2   2    7.14285E-4    2719.0    1.0      0.0
O2+ 32.00    5.31E-26  2    0.2   2    5.58659E-5    2256.0    1.0      1.0
N2+ 28.016   4.65E-26  2    0.2   2    1.90114E-5    3371.0    1.0      1.0
O+  16.00    2.65E-26  0    0.0   0    0.0           0.0       1.0      1.0
N+  14.008  2.325E-26  0    0.0   0    0.0           0.0       1.0      1.0
NO+ 30.008   4.98E-26  2    0.2   2    7.14285E-4    2719.0    1.0      1.0
e   0.001  9.10938188E-31 0 0.0   0    0.0           0.0       1.0     -1.0
```

air.vss file:

```
# VSS collision model parameters for each species

# diameter (mass)
# omega (unitless)
# tref (temperature)
# alpha (unitless)
# Zrotinf (unitless)
# T* (temperature)
# C1 (temperature)
# C2 (temperature^(1/3))

O2   3.96E-10    0.77  273.15  1.4   16.5 113.5 56.5 153.5
N2   4.07E-10    0.74  273.15  1.6   18.1 91.5 9.1 220.0
O    3.0E-10     0.80  273.15  1.0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
N    3.0E-10     0.80  273.15  1.0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
NO   4.0E-10     0.80  273.15  1.0   7.5 119.0 9.10 220.00
O2+  3.96E-10    0.77  273.15  1.4   16.5 113.5 56.5 153.5
N2+  4.07E-10    0.74  273.15  1.6   18.1 91.5 9.1 220.0
O+   3.0E-10     0.80  273.15  1.0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
N+   3.0E-10     0.80  273.15  1.0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
NO+  4.0E-10     0.80  273.15  1.0   7.5 119.0 9.10 220.00
e    7.0E-13     0.50  273.15  1.0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

data.lid file:

```
surf file from Pizza.py

4 points
4 lines

Points

1 0 -0.00250
2 0.1 -0.00250
3 0.1 0.00250
4 0 0.00250

Lines

1 2 1
2 3 2
3 4 3
4 1 4
```

Comment: What is different between your test case and theirs?

Comment: That's what I can't figure out. I tried reproducing the same test case but I'm getting different results.

Comment: Validation means you are building a hypersonic body and testing it to validate the software. That is the *only* meaning of validation in this context. If you are writing your own code to try to get the same result, that isn't validation. How are the chemical reactions modelled?

Comment: @PhilSweet Yes, I'm trying to validate the software. I'm not making any changes to the code. I'm just writing my own input file for the problem. I have added some additional information that might solve your query.